# How to access CCDirector inside objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-js

Hi i am fairly new to cocos2d-js and want to access `CCDirector` inside the objective c to display a view controller.

What all header libraries do we need to include to access `CCDirector`?

Answer (score 0):

You must `#import "cocos2d.h"` then you can simply access `CCDirector` as a singleton object through the following method call:

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector];
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita, I included #import "cocos2d.h" but sill i am facing an issue.. 'Reciever type CCDirector is not an objective c class' and also it says CCDirector is deprecated

Comment: @SiddhantJain What's the issue?

Comment: Facing two issues .. a) Reciever type CCDirector is not an objective c class' b) CCDirector is deprecated. Second one is a warning though

Comment: i have included cocos2d.h inside my obejctive-c code (Util.m) file.. I am not really sure if we can do that or not..

Comment: Your answer is correct for cocos2d-iphone but not for cocos2d-js/cocos2d-x

Answer (score 0):

use RootViewController to present a new viewController
or add subview to UIWindow

watch codes in AppController.mm

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 0):

To access director from C++/Objective-C you need to include cocos2d header:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
...
cocos2d::Director::getInstance();
```